# fragment,viewPager,list view and adapter don't work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I have this problem:

> "Error:(51, 16) error: method addFrag in class
>   ScrollableTabsActivity.ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied to given
>   types; required: TwoFragment,String found: OneFragment,String reason:
>   actual argument OneFragment cannot be converted to TwoFragment by
>   method invocation conversion".

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

CODE is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.EightFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FiveFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FourFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.NineFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SevenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TwoFragment;

public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "PIZZE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
        adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
        adapter.addFrag(new NineFragment(), "NINE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(TwoFragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Planet> objects;


    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public  class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public String quantità;



    }


@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);

        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((Main) context);
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        return row;
    }


    public ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.selected)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your method :

```
public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
```

Comment: in line "        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "PIZZE");
"

Comment: update your addFrag method as i mention in answer. Only first line show error. Try to remove first and second line and I think third line also shows red line.

Comment: yes, i updated method as you mentioned it in answer...but now only OneFragment() is underline in red...now i renamed OneFragment to Fragment  and it is ok

Comment: how can upload in OneFragment id.listview?